# Issue with command prompt (windows) and python script after restarting script

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write a CLI program with python in windows. I recently came across an issue with argparse and my work-around was to clear the command prompt and re-run my script with the same arguments using this code:

```
sys.stdout.flush
os.execl(sys.executable, 'python', __file__, *sys.argv[1:])
```

This works perfectly until I try to input something into my program. I have this perpetual loop in my code which allows me to input a string and have it echoed back to me:

```
while True:
    action = input("> ")
    print(f'typed {action}')
```

but once I reach that point in the code, it does not work, this is my output:
[image: faulty code output]

This is the expected output up until after the red "Ready."
for some reason, the command prompt alternates between an input to my script, and an input to the command prompt, which are both prefaced with the wrong text, the ">" should be an input to my script, but that input is being sent to the command prompt, and the "...\raspi>" should be an input to the command prompt, but that input is being sent to my script. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening? Why it's alternating between my script and regular command prompt?

Comment: Don't do that.  `execl` on WIndows is a hack.  The original process ends and goes back to the shell, and you get a new process attached to the same stdin/stdout, so they compete for the resources.  There must be a better way for you to restart your processing.

Comment: @TimRoberts do you have any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: I don't know what problem you're working around.  The usual way is to have your `main` as a function, and have some kind of `while True:` / `main()` loop, along with a way to escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I came to was to realize that the `cprint()` function of the `colorama.py` library does not return text and instead just calls the print function (I should have been able to deduce that through the name of the function). So all I had to do was to not set the description of my parser to a `cprint()` function and instead call `cprint()` when it's needed.